# kafka consumer group failing on 0.11 3.0.0 version

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I am getting this error when running the script on kafka 0.11 version

```
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to The broker only supports OffsetFetchRequest v1, but we need v2 or newer to request all topic partitions.
```

**Dependencies** 
compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.11.0-kafka-3.0.0'

**Command**

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --new-consumer --describe --bootstrap-server bootstrap:9092 --group myid
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Make sure that host ( `--bootstrap-server bootstrap:9092`) is correct.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Error seems to be quite clear -- there is a mismatch between versions of the broker and client library that you're using. 
According to [Kafka source](https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/63544647897e45ae58546020a3d128e048fdd104/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/requests/OffsetFetchRequest.java), this exception is thrown when broker is back-leveled (version < 2) and you're trying to retrieve offset info for all partitions.